# Creature's treasures and legend points

Tags: earthdawn-1e

The lightning lizard's eyes are worth 150 silver each, thus 300 total.
It is mentioned they are treasures worth legend points. Are they worth the full 300 legend or a fraction of? Are they worth it when they sell them or upon collection?

I am playing Earthdawn First Edition.

Comment: Now that we have a tag for Earthdawn First Edition, you needn't write that out at the end of each question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does looting treasures worth legend points work?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48379/how-does-looting-treasures-worth-legend-points-work)

Comment: well, it doesn't cover the same thing, considering i asked both question.
Plus that question is simpler, and might receive a less complete answer that wouldnt cut it for the other question.

Comment: It doesn't exactly… but maybe it should? Do we really need two questions about how assigning LPs from creature parts works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Awarding Legend Awards** section in *Gamemaster's Compendium* is quite brief.

It only tells us that

> An adventure should provide a payoff of one Legend Award’s worth of Treasure Legend Points per character, and should include the treasures that many creatures possess. When you are deciding what creatures you want the characters to meet, remember to note any treasure those creatures carry and include it in your total Treasure Legend Points. Creature treasure is listed in each creature’s description.

Exactly nothing in *Player's/Gamemaster's Compendium* tells us the correlation between Legend Points and treasure price, but 1 sp per Legend Point is a good baseline estimate.
You may consult the table of appropriate award sizes per circle at *Gamemaster's Compendium*, p95, to correct the LP-to-sp ratio as needed.

Liquidating the (bloody) bits is another thing altogether; the party needs to find a buyer, and even then, *Haggle* rolls could affect the price.

Comment: i guess the LP should be awarded upon showing to people who might be interested if the whole thing is dependent on the value. Not a bad idea, the haggle roll.
Thank you, friend.